# How to pass state value to Graphql Query

Tags: graphql, react-apollo, express-graphql, graphql-tag

I am new in Graphql and React. I need help. I tried get query from user like GraphiQL. I want get query from user and return result. I made a query. If I write query, it works but otherwise I am getting error. My code block as below like and works :

My code block like and works :

```
let BLOCK_QUERY = gql`
    query {
        block {
            id
            type
        }
    }
`;
```

I try get query from user like this but is not work:

```
let BLOCK_QUERY = gql`
    this.state.block
`;
```

Maybe I think I will do things close to that.

```
let BLOCK_QUERY = gql`
    ${this.state.block}
`;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear.
Start by creating a github repo and pushing your code there. That way we can better help you.